# Updating large amounts of data in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I have problem with updating my database. I have iMac i5 16GB Ram with SSD + MAMP PRO.

I have this model:

```
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\SoftDeletes;
use Kalnoy\Nestedset\NodeTrait;
use Spatie\Sluggable\HasSlug;
use Spatie\Sluggable\SlugOptions;

class Category extends Model
{
    use ScopeActiveTrait,
        NodeTrait,
        HasSlug,
        SoftDeletes;

    protected $guarded = ['id'];

    protected $fillable = [
        'category_name',
        'description',
        'keywords',
        'content',
        'enable',
        'photo',
        'order',
        'slug',
        '_lft',
        '_rgt',
        'parent_id',
        'value'
    ];

    public $timestamps = false;

    protected $dates = [
        'deleted_at'
    ];

    protected $casts = [
        'order' => 'integer',
        'enable'=>'boolean'
    ];

    /**
     * Get the options for generating the slug.
     */
    public function getSlugOptions() : SlugOptions
    {
        return SlugOptions::create()
            ->generateSlugsFrom('category_name')
            ->slugsShouldBeNoLongerThan(160)
            ->saveSlugsTo('slug');
    }

}
```

Migration:

```
class CreateFailedJobsTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('failed_jobs', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->string('uuid')->unique();
            $table->text('connection');
            $table->text('queue');
            $table->longText('payload');
            $table->longText('exception');
            $table->timestamp('failed_at')->useCurrent();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('failed_jobs');
    }
}
```

And controller:

```
public function index(Category $category)
    {
        echo 'START';
        $categories = $category->where('value', null)->orWhere('value', '')->orderBy('id', 'ASC')->get();
        foreach ($categories as $item) {
            $path = null;
            $tmpProduct = $item->ancestorsAndSelf($item->id);
            foreach ($tmpProduct as $pathItem) {
                $path .= $pathItem->category_name . ' - ';
            }
            $path = substr($path, 0, -3);
            $item->update(['value' => $path]);
        }

        echo 'finish';
    }
```

It's work fine, but very slow. I use this package in my model: https://packagist.org/packages/kalnoy/nestedset

How can I optimize this update? My database has 170,000 records.

Please help me

Comment: you can make command for this also you can  use chunk

Comment: command doc : https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/artisan#command-structure

Comment: you can make command like first 1-500 records update after that 500-1000 record update ... it will be take time but if you use this method or flow then not more load on your system... don't update all data at single time

Comment: Command starts from CLI?

Comment: you think about something like this: https://pastebin.com/vkDwg3j6 ?

Comment: Yes , take two variable like starting id and ending id then make command and make query like  between 1-5000 ids updated after command end then fire second time 5000-10000 ids ...command is very useful for this type of operation...

Comment: i try my best but i have no time so ... i give basic idea and i think its help.  i modify your code ... check https://pastebin.com/DC21FMas

Comment: when you this type of operation like delete , update operation then command run in background /CMD ...